# Using the output of salt to be used as input for an SLS state or pillar?

Tags: python, salt-stack

For example, I want to find all nodes with a certain tag, grab their IP address, then generate a config file to distribute to those nodes.

A use case might be a database that needs to know about every other node, but can have nodes added and removed at any time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **Salt Mine** to do it. First, distribute this configuration to all the Minions:

```
mine_functions:
  grains.item:
    - roles
    - fqdn_ip4
```

With that configuration, every Minion will publish those two grains to all other minions. More details about Mine [here](http://docs.saltstack.com/topics/mine/index.html).

Now, we can create a file with all the names with role=db.

```
/tmp/mydbhosts:
  file:
    - managed
    - source: salt://example/myhosts
    - template: mako
```

The template example/myhosts:

```
% for minion, peer_grains in salt['mine.get']('*', 'grains.items').items():
% if "db" in peer_grains["role"]:
minion peer_grains["fqdn_ip4"]
% endif
% endfor
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a hacky solution, so hopefully someone else can find a better answer.

The approach is to create a Python script that runs `salt` to grab the YAML output of `network.ip_addrs eth0` then use that to call a particular sls with a pillar.

I made an example prototype which still needs to be implemented and tweaked:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import yaml


# Query all db nodes for their ip addresses
data = subprocess.check_output(
    'salt -G "role:db" network.ip_addrs eth0',
    shell=True
)
data = yaml.load(data)

# Parse and reshuffle for pillar input
addrs = []
for a in data.values():
        addrs.append(a[0])
addrs = yaml.dump({'db_peers': addrs})

# Update configuration file on each node
data = subprocess.check_output(
    'salt -G "role:db" state.sls db.configure pillar="{}"'.format(addrs),
    shell=True
)
```

This will execute something along the lines of:

```
salt -G "role:db" state.sls db.configure pillar="db_peers: [1.2.3.4, 2.3.4.5]"
```

This could potentially be put into a module, but I'm not sure how to nicely ask salt-minion to communicate to the master to run `db.configure` on other nodes. I could simply execute the command similar to the script above.