# How do I use the IP addresses of machines matching a grain in a Salt State file

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I'm creating a formula/state file that adds an `iptables` rule:

```
ipt_allow:
  iptables.append:
    - table: filter
    - chain: INPUT
    - jump: ACCEPT
    - match: state
    - connstate: 'NEW,ESTABLISHED'
    - dport: 6666
    - proto: tcp
    - source: 'ip1, ip2, ip3, ...'
```

I don't want to hard code the IP addresses in `source`. `ip1`, `ip2`, and `ip3` are the IP addresses of minions that match the grain `role:role1`. That way, if I ever add more minions with the grain `role1` down the road, they'll get added to the iptables rule once I rerun this state file. How do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it. This can be done using Salt mine functions.

1. `/srv/pillar/mines.sls`:

   ```
   mine_functions:
     network.ip_addrs:
       - eth1
   ```

   This makes the `network.ip_addrs` available to the master and minions, specifically the `eth1` interface.
2. `/srv/pillar/top.sls`:

   ```
   base:
     '*':
       - mines
   ```

   This applies the pillar (hence the mine function) to all the minions.
3. Now you can use the `mine.get` function in your state files to call that mine function. This is what I used in my case:

   ```
   {% for server, addrs in salt['mine.get']('role:role1', 'network.ip_addrs', expr_form='grain').items() %}
   ipt_allow_{{ server }}:
     iptables.append:
       - table: filter
       - chain: INPUT
       - jump: ACCEPT
       - match: state
       - connstate: 'NEW,ESTABLISHED'
       - dport: 6666
       - proto: tcp
       - source: {{ addrs[0] }}
   {% endfor %}
   ```

   Where:

   - `salt['mine.get']` calls the `mine.get` function,
   - `('role:role1', 'network.ip_addrs', expr_form='grain').items()` tells the function to match minions that have `role1` as the value of `role` which is a grain (`expr_form='grain'`) and get its `network.ip_addrs`.
   - The output is the matched minion id (I believe) and the result of `network.ip_addrs`, so we store that in `server` and `addrs`.
   - The `for` loop loops goes around creating a new ID every time using the value in `{{ server }}` and substituting the IP address in `{{ addrs[0] }}`.

Links that helped:

- http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/mine/index.html
- http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.mine.html
- [Using the output of salt to be used as input for an SLS state or pillar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897796/using-the-output-of-salt-to-be-used-as-input-for-an-sls-state-or-pillar?rq=1)